# How can I find why Android market is filtering my app on certain phone

Tags: android, compatibility, android-manifest, google-play

we have an app for Android called OnTheRoad (market://search/?q=pname:eu.inmite.prj.otr.aclient ), but for certain reason, it is not visible if I access Android Market from Vodafone 845 phone (Huawei Joy).

The phone has QVGA screen resolution and runs Android 2.1 system. The app is 1.5+ compatible and has enabled support for small screens in its manifest. Another our app has completely same settings and it is perfectly visible in the Market from VF845.

Is there any way, how can I check, based on what criteria is my app filtered for certain phone model? Thanks.

Comment: would be interested in a solution too...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer you're looking for is available on Google's [developer site, here.](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/market-filters.html)

Comment: I don't see how that document answers the specific question: why is the app filtered for a particular _model_ of phone?

Comment: In short, it actually doesn't filter the models themselves. The operating system itself checks to see what the phone does and does not, and can and can not, do. IE, if it has a GPS chip, or if it can support intense 3D graphics, and then filters the results based on that. Google doesn't have a database saying "The LG Lucid can NOT have this app." The phone itself determines that. So far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

This is a huge issue with "Copy protected" applications. You should use market licensing instead although it is a pain to test and implement. Are your apps copy protected because im guessing this is the issue. Hope it helps.